# How to purge another OS and install Ubuntu safely?

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I've been testing out different linux os's and was beforedhand on fedora. A few weeks back, when booting up fedora, my computer crashed. When i tried to boot it back up, it would freeze at the BIOS POST.

Today I decided to give it another try, and downloaded 12.04 on a CD Rom to see if I could load it. I can get it to load up the CD and i'm able to try out Ubuntu but when I go to install it it tells me I have to have at least 4.5 GB available drive space and it won't let me continue.

The problem is I can't figure out how to delete files on the hard drive to free it up to be able to install ubuntu. Do you think the hard drive fried back with that crash under fedora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see if Ubuntu running from the CD will let you install GParted.  Then GParted may be able to either partition out enough space for installing Ubuntu or could format the drive and allow Ubuntu to install.  This second option, formatting, will erase everything on the drive.  Make sure there is nothing on the drive that you want to keep before you format it.

Comment: GParted is already included in the distribution (at least it's included in 12.04LTS ) so it should runs out of the box on a live session. No need to install.

Comment: I figured it out. I just unplugged and plugged back in my hard drive and it magically worked. Thanks for the reply though, hope this helps others that look at this!